# JQuery If Else statement never executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using a simple if else statement to check for response from a POST form.

This is weird: I can check for response in form of error. Using elseif: or else: just does absolut nothing. Even though the response is valid.

Current code:

```
post_data = {
    'someData': someData
}

// Ajax post data to server
$.post('register.php', post_data, function(response) {

    if (response.type == 'error') {
        if (response.errorType == 'something') {
            $("#someThing").addClass('has-error');
        }
    } else {
        window.location.reload(true);
    }

}, 'json');
```

This is so weird. I've tried to insert alerts to really check if the else statement ran in background or something.

When the response is: "error" the error statement is executed.

However when the response is: success/done/cleared/failed etc. (whatever i try) nothing happens.

I receive the respond in console - but JQuery doesnt run the } else { ... statement.

Comment: What does `console.log(response.type)` contains?

Comment: try promises: `$.post().done().fail()` or `$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});`

Comment: The console.log doesnt return any values? However in network i can see the data being returned?

Comment: Also tried to console.log("LOG START"); just inside the post. However when receiving  "error" from response everything is both logged and working

Comment: It could be that somehow the service you are calling has mixed up the HTTP status responses. Status 200 OK should be returned in case of success, and possibly another value (4xx or 5xx) in case of failure. Maybe this got swapped. Or maybe there are other reasons why it returns 4xx or 5xx. The $.post() only executes the function if it receives 200 OK.

Comment: Yes, Request Method:POST - Status Code:200 OK. The info is being sent to the file and info is inserted into the DB intended. But the else statement is skipped :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually its not what you think.

The function is only called on Success. For error handling you have to chain another function

For example try this:

```
post_data = {   
            'someData':someData
        }

        // Ajax post data to server
        $.post('register.php', post_data).done(function (response) {
            // This is your success function
             window.location.reload(true);
        })
       .fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Post error: " + errorThrown);
            $("#someThing").addClass('has-error');
        });
```

I hope this help you to understand that weird behavior :P

jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) have different handling functions for different jQuery version. so better to use $.ajax

Comment: Ill try and get back (Y)

Comment: Just read quickly about this. Might have something to do with my PHP ? however Thank you. I'll accept this answer as it solved the actual problem of OP. (Y)